# How input visible from select value when returning from another page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select

When selecting `1_preduzece`, the input field `my_field` is displayed, however, when data is entered into this input and the user switches to another html page, in case he returns to the page this input field disappears but `1_preduzece` remains selected. How to keep this input visible when returning from another page if `1_preduzece` is selected.

```
<select required="" aria-required="true" name="svojina" id="svojina" onchange="showMessage(); showDiv(this)">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Odaberi:</option>
  <option value="1_preduzece">Korisnik 1</option>
  <option value="2_preduzece">Korisnik 2</option>
</select>

<p id="vrsta"></p>

<script>
function showMessage() {
    var x = document.getElementById("svojina").value;
    document.getElementById("vrsta").innerHTML = "";

    if (x == "1_preduzece") {
        document.getElementById("vrsta").innerHTML = "";
    }

    if (x == "2_preduzece") {
        document.getElementById("vrsta").innerHTML = "";    
    }
}
</script>


<div id="hidden_div" style="display: none;">

<input id="my_field" type="text" name="my" maxlength="5" size="30" disabled="true" onkeyup="saveValue(this);">
</div>


<script>
  // input to track
  let field = document.getElementById("my_field"); 
  if (sessionStorage.getItem("autosave")) {
    // Restore a content of the input
    field.value = sessionStorage.getItem("autosave");
  }
 
  // Listen for changes in the input field
  field.addEventListener("change", function() {
    // save value into sessionStorage object 
    sessionStorage.setItem("autosave", field.value);
  });
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
function showDiv(select){
   if(select.value=="1_preduzece"){
    document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('my_field').disabled = false;

   } else {
    document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('my_field').disabled = true;
   }
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is a browser cache of sorts. The best way to circumvent that is to run a javascript function on page init to reset your form values.

In vanilla JS:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
   document.querySelector('select[name=svojina]').value='';
})
```

In JQuery

```
$(function() {
   $('select[name=svojina]').val('');
})
```